# Counting number of rows from other table with field value based on ids selected from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
conversation_folder {
    conversation_folder_id,
    user_id
    ...
}

conversation_user {
    conversation_id
    owner_user_id
    is_unread
}

conversation_folder_relations {
    conversation_id
    conversation_folder_id
    user_id
}
```

I am wanting to select the record out of the `conversation_folder` table, however I would like to include the number of conversations that are in the folder that aren't read, for a specific `user_id` (`owner_user_id` in the `conversation_user` table).

Is this possible with one query, or will I have to get the folders, and then run another query to get the unread count?

EDIT:

For increased obviousness, this query provides the required result, but it involves multiple subqueries, which is far from ideal:

```
SELECT conversation_folder.*,
(
    SELECT COUNT(conversation_id)
    FROM conversation_user
    WHERE conversation_id IN (
            SELECT conversation_id
            FROM conversation_folder_relations
            WHERE conversation_folder_relations.user_id = conversation_user.owner_user_id
                AND conversation_folder_id = conversation_folder.conversation_folder_id
            )
        AND is_unread = 1
    ) AS unread_count
FROM conversation_folder
WHERE conversation_folder.user_id = ?
```

Comment: Some sample table data and expected result would be nice.

Comment: here is an example using sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18cc8/7

Answer (score 0):

Querying both separately is probably best. This could also be solved with a join over the columns user_id and owner_user_id and then a count on the resulting table. But joins are notoriously bad for performance when used poorly on SqlServer, maybe MySql is different. This is untested since I've only worked with SqlServer.

```
SELECT count(conversation_id)
FROM conversation_user
INNER JOIN conversation_folder_relations
ON conversation_user.owner_user_id = conversation_folder_relations.user_id;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Comment: nice place to start but is still far from OP question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT conversation_folder_id, count(conversation_id)
 FROM conversation_user  cu
 JOIN conversation_folder_relations cfr
   ON cu.conversation_id = cfr.conversation_id
 WHERE 
     cu.owner_user_id = @user_id
 AND is_unread = true
 GROUP BY conversation_folder_id
```

This need `@user_id` be in all conversation_id for your model. Otherwise you would need a `LEFT JOIN` but your question doesnt say anything about it.

I will assume you create the conversation_id for every user and set the is_unread to true every time a new conversation is created.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't provide the correct data, please see my edit.

Comment: Let me check, but you should follow  jarlh and provide some data sample and desire output.